# radiusclient on debian 9

Tags: freeradius, debian-stretch, xl2tpd

I have debian 9 server and want to setup a Xl2tp with radius authentication.

When I add `plugin radius.so` on my ppp options, it try to read `/etc/radiusclient` and unfortunately I don't have `libfreeradius-client` package on debian stretch repository.

Does anyone have any idea about that ?

```
xl2tpd[31455]: "/etc/ppp/options"
xl2tpd[31455]: Call established with a.x.y.z, Local: 39429, Remote: 34750, Serial: 23
pppd[31488]: Plugin radius.so loaded.
pppd[31488]: RADIUS plugin initialized.
pppd[31488]: Plugin pppol2tp.so loaded.
pppd[31488]: Plugin radius.so loaded.
pppd[31488]: RADIUS plugin initialized.
pppd[31488]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
pppd[31488]: using channel 26
pppd[31488]: Using interface ppp0
pppd[31488]: Connect: ppp0 <-->
pppd[31488]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1440
pppd[31488]: PPPoL2TP options: lnsmode tid 33229 sid 39429 debugmask 0
pppd[31488]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1440
pppd[31488]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1440> <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xcf4c7130>]
pppd[31488]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1410> <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x7852c87e>]
pppd[31488]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mru 1410> <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x7852c87e>]
pppd[31488]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mru 1440> <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xcf4c7130>]
pppd[31488]: PPPoL2TP options: lnsmode tid 33229 sid 39429 debugmask 0
pppd[31488]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xcf4c7130]
pppd[31488]: sent [CHAP Challenge id=0x32 <b601612440ebbf8a284b6fe85930100783775546>, name = "XL2TP"]
pppd[31488]: rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x7852c87e]
pppd[31488]: rcvd [CHAP Response id=0x32 <0dd24953c6828d16bfad2d2267e2c647>, name = "user"]
pppd[31488]: rc_read_config: can't open /etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf: No such file or directory
pppd[31488]: RADIUS: Can't read config file /etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf
pppd[31488]: Peer skill39 failed CHAP authentication
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*libfreeradius-client* is deprecated and replaced with [libradcli4](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libradcli4)
also configuration folder changed from `/etc/radiusclient` to `/etc/radcli`
and some attribute changed for example:

```
root@localhost#grep NAS-IP  /etc/radcli/dictionary
ATTRIBUTE       NAS-IP-Address          4       ipv4addr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install freeradius-utils libpam-radius-auth
```

and edit your config to : `/etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf`